# Scale path from center

Tags: html, svg

I have the following SVG graphic:

```
<svg version="1.1" id="diagram" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="375px" height="150px">
    <path d="M45,11.5H33.333c0.735-1.159,1.167-2.528,1.167-4C34.5,3.364,31.136,0,27,0s-7.5,3.364-7.5,7.5c0,1.472,0.432,2.841,1.167,4H9l-9,32h54L45,11.5z M22.5,7.5C22.5,5.019,24.519,3,27,3s4.5,2.019,4.5,4.5c0,1.752-1.017,3.257-2.481,4h-4.037 C23.517,10.757,22.5,9.252,22.5,7.5z" id="control"/>
</svg>
```

I want to programmatically change the scale of this object, but I want it to scale from the center point.

I've tried wrapping it around a `<g>` tag, like so

```
<g transform="translate(0,0)">
<path x="0" y="0" id="control" transform="scale(2)">...</path>
</g>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. It seems that scaling a path requires manipulation of the `path`'s matrix, which seems horrifically difficult. Annoyingly, it's easy to scale using additive="sum" property but in this instance, I am not using a transform animation.

Can anyone help me out?

**Edit:** Managed to get this working nicely, for anyone who is stuck on the same thing, here is a nice way of doing it programmatically:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("control");
var bBox = elem.getBBox();
var scaleX = 2;
var scaleY = 2;
$(elem).attr("transform", `scale(${scaleX}, ${scaleY}) translate(${-bBox.width/2},${-bBox.height/2})`);
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

If you know the coordinates of the center point, then you can combine a translate and scale in one transformation. The translation is calculated as: `(1 - scale) * currentPosition`.

If the center is `(10, 20)` and you are scaling by `3` then translate by `(1 - 3)*10, (1 - 3)*20` = `(-20, -40)`:

```
<g transform="translate(-20, -40) scale(3)">
    <path d="M45,11.5H33.333c0.735-1.159,1.167-2.528,1.167-4C34.5,3.364,31.136,0,27,0s-7.5,3.364-7.5,7.5c0,1.472,0.432,2.841,1.167,4H9l-9,32h54L45,11.5z M22.5,7.5C22.5,5.019,24.519,3,27,3s4.5,2.019,4.5,4.5c0,1.752-1.017,3.257-2.481,4h-4.037 C23.517,10.757,22.5,9.252,22.5,7.5z" id="control"/>
</g>
```

The transformations are applied in reverse order from the one they are declared, so in the example, above, the `scale` is performed first and then the `translate`. Scaling affects the coordinates so the translation here is in scaled coordinates.

You can calculate the center point programmatically using `element.getBBox()`.

Comment: Thank for you this, will answer as correct when I can. Out of interest, element.getBBox() just returns a SVG rect with values  height: 43.5, width: 54, x: 0, y: 0... would I use the width and height values / 2?

Comment: Yes, exactly your center point is `(width / 2 + x, height / 2 + y)`.

Comment: Note that if the path isn't at `0, 0`, you need to add the `bbox.x` & `bbox.y` values to the calculation, e.g. `(1-scale) * (bbox.x + bbox.width/2)`

Comment: I believe you can avoid the math for the center by doing an additional translation. Example, if the center is `(cx, cy)` you can do `transform="translate(cx, cy) scale(3) translate(-cx, -cy)"`

Comment: Also look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34937054/235415) for completeness.

Comment: @urraka Thanks. This should be an answer itself. Really helped me out here.

Answer (score 28):

You can alter the origin to center:

```
.scaled-path-svg {
  svg {
    path {
      transform-origin: center;
      transform: scale(1.1);
      transform-box: fill-box;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Such a life saver

Comment: Note that this scales a shape around the center of the WHOLE SVG, not the center of the SHAPE. There is no way easy way of scaling a shape up/down from its own center without doing a cumbersome calculation like in the accepted answer.

Comment: how about adding an additional `transform-box:fill-box;` to it.

Comment: this with what @ViktorBorítás suggested should be the accepted solution. simple and clean

Answer (score 3):

The answer provided by [aetheria](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11671373/235415) earlier is great. There is another thing to take care of as well -- stroke-width, so that the outline stays of the same width while the object scales. Usage:

```
stroke-width: (1/scaling-factor)
```

So, if your scaling is by say 2, then:

```
stroke-width: (0.5)
```

NOTE: You shouldn't missout the `transform: translate(...) scale(2)` as mentioned by aetheria.

Comment: or can use `non-scaling-stroke` attribute. 
more info: https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/how-to-disable-scaling-for-stroke-width/