# What is the math involved in a SVG scaling transformation around a point?

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm working with an inherited codebase in Raphael.js, so I'm trying to reverse-engineer some of this code. I have a set of transformations that occur on a set of paths that represent alphabetical character shapes, which are grouped together as words/character strings:

```
shape.attr('path', Raphael.transformPath(shape.attr('path'), ['t', x, y]));
shape.attr('path', Raphael.transformPath(shape.attr('path'), ['s', sizeByScale, sizeByScale, +**bb[0]**, 0]));
shape.attr('path', Raphael.transformPath(shape.attr('path'), ['t', totalShift, 0]));
```

Looking at these three, here's what happens line-by-line:

1. The shape is adjusted based on the position of the letter group it's in (i.e., shape 'A' in a group of shapes 'Apple' is at x, y, so translate along that)
2. The scale of the path is adjusted **around value `bb[0]` on the x axis (highlighted in the code)** into place to look correct in SVG-land in the browser (these paths come from Cufon)
3. The shape is shifted to the right based on preceding characters

I would like to refactor this code so that I can instead scale shapes individually, and then adjust their x/y translations later without having to worry about the "scale around" effect caused by bb[0]. How do I figure out what the x-adjustment based on bb[0] is? Let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: Is it possible to put up a working jsfiddle of the key bits ?

Comment: I can give it a shot later tonight, but the code is pretty involved. Might have a potential solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671100/scale-path-from-center