# d3.js - circle animation with a slider

Tags: javascript, animation, d3.js

I'm trying to create an animation where a circle pulses (big to small to big again etc.). The rate of pulsing would be controlled by a slider, sort of like [this one](http://www.jasondavies.com/bubbles/). However, I'm not sure whether to use zoom or transform or something else. The code included is a modification of [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3828981), but it is obviously not right. I put a demo at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c92HP/1/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<style>
 .mesh {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: .25px;
}
.start {
  fill: brown;
  stroke: brown;
}
.end {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1560,
height = 900,
radius = 10;

var p0 = [250, 200, 120],
    p1 = [270, 200, 20];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .call(transition, p0, p1);

    svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data([p0, p1])
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("class", function (d, i) {
        return i ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .attr("cx", function (d) {
    return d[0];
    })
    .attr("cy", function (d) {
    return d[1];
    })
    .attr("r", function (d) {
    return d[2] / 2 - .5;
    });

    function transition(svg, start, end) {
    var center = [width / 2, height / 2],
    i = d3.interpolateZoom(start, end);

    svg.attr("transform", transform(start))
        .transition()
        .delay(250)
        .duration(i.duration * 4)
        .attrTween("transform", function () {
            return function (t) {
                return transform(i(t));
            };
        })
    .each("end", function () {
        d3.select(this).call(transition, end, start);
    });

    function transform(p) {
        var k = height / p[2];
        return "translate(" + (center[0] - p[0] * k) + "," + (center[1] - p[1] * k) + ")scale(" + k + ")";
    }
}


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood what you're trying to do correctly, you're overcomplicating it quite a lot. All you need is a transition that calls itself:

```
svg.append("circle")
  .attr("cx", width/2)
  .attr("cy", height/2)
  .attr("r", minRadius)
  .call(transition, minRadius, maxRadius);

function transition(element, start, end) {
  element.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("r", end)
    .each("end", function() { d3.select(this).call(transition, end, start); });
}
```

and a slider:

```
d3.select("body").append("input")
  .attr("type", "range")
  .attr("min", 500)
  .attr("max", 2000)
  .attr("value", duration)
  .on("change", function() { duration = this.value; });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4RmZP/1/). The main thing is that at the end of the transition, it initialises a new one with reversed values.

Comment: Simple yet brilliant!

Comment: Lars, this worked wonderfully. Thank you! I'm doing a set of animations on different shapes (the circle was one of them). I was wondering if you knew how to apply this technique to a shape other than a circle, like a square or a cloud. When I try it, it slides diagonally across the page instead of staying still http://jsfiddle.net/aucontraire/9fH2h/1/ . Is there a way to keep it still and make it seem like it's expanding from the center?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671100/scale-path-from-center) should help with that.

Comment: I am very close but the transition back is not as smooth as the transition in. http://jsfiddle.net/aucontraire/97AMA/

Comment: Not sure if I understand -- there's no transition back to the smaller size, is there?

Comment: I guess there isn't a transition back. It just skips back to the smaller size, hence, the choppiness.

Comment: You just need to follow exactly the same pattern as in my answer -- http://jsfiddle.net/97AMA/2/

Comment: Awesome! I just saw it. That's exactly what I was hoping for. Thank you.