# D3.js - animate point along path w/ variable speed

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, transition, svg-animate

I have three arrays of points that define three paths, and need to move a different point along each path w/ the option of changing speed. The three arrays are contained in another array, so the structure basically looks like this:

```
DataByDays = [ [(array of x1's), (array of y1's)], [(array of x2's), (array of y2's)], [(array of x3's), (array of y3's)]
```

I have already plotted the paths and have an array that holds them similarly, like:

```
PathArray = [path1, path2, path3]
```

Currently, I've created each of the trackers:

```
trackers = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataByDays)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("cx", function(d){return d[0][0];}) //x coord @ start of path 
        .attr("cy", function(d){return d[0][1];}) //y coord @ start of path
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", "black");
```

I've tried to adapt a variety of solutions to similar problems but nothing has worked. I'd like to start with just getting the trackers to move along the path, but also need to incorporate the ability to change the speed at which the trackers move with a slider that I've already created.

Comment: Modifying transitions after they have been started is tricky, you may be better off by having a series of transitions (e.g. for each intermediate point) where you can adjust the speed of the transition. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21738321/d3-js-circle-animation-with-a-slider) for a related question.