# Why when I use transform scale it moves the animated div's position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

EDIT : I don't think this question should be marked as a possible duplicate because It deals with distracting SVG info and I think unnecessary math.

In the keyframes section below when I leave out the `transform: scale` the div shows up in the middle of the page. That's what I want. Now I wanted to make it so that the div start out bigger and the opacity fadesIn while the div gets smaller and the center of the div should be at the center of the page. When I add  transform scale the div doesn't animate in the center anymore. why? and how can I fix it?

```
   .popup{
        position: absolute;
        width:400px;
        height: 300px;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        background: limegreen;
        border: 5px solid silver;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        transition: all 2s;
        opacity: 0;

    }
    .anim{
        animation: popAnim 2s forwards;
    }
    @keyframes popAnim{
        0%{
            transform : scale(1.5);
            opacity: 0;
        }
        100%{
            transform: scale(1);
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<div class="popup">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Error inventore molestiae, dignissimos ducimus adipisci sint suscipit dolor blanditiis fugit, quia aspernatur quos, facere nostrum! Distinctio praesentium saepe, quaerat modi fuga.</div>
<button class="click">click me</button>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready( function(){
        $(".click").on("click", function(){
            $(".popup").toggleClass("anim")
        })
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scale path from center](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671100/scale-path-from-center)

Comment: its not moving, its just zooming out based on center..  http://jsfiddle.net/josangel555/6rkLc7jc/

Comment: EDIT : I don't think this question should be marked as a possible duplicate because It deals with distracting SVG info and I think unnecessary math.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In declaraing `transform : scale(1.5);` you're overriding `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);`, so `transform: scale(1.5)` is the equivalent of `transform: translate(0, 0) scale(1.5)`.

Instead, you need to stack your transform values so the translate is maintained. The keyframe animation becomes:

```
  @keyframes popAnim{
    0%{
      transform : translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
      opacity: 0;
    }
    100%{
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Question : at 0% **and** 100%  the div is moving 50% of the width to the left? so it's moving 50% 2 times? I didn't think I needed to do that. Thanks for your answer. The effect is what I was looking for

Comment: No, in terms of position it isn't moving at all, only in scale. You specified `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` before the animation (to create vertical and horizontal centering). As the transform property must be shared for translate and scale values, we had to specify the translate again in the animation to prevent it from being overridden so rather than moving, it's just staying where it is and only animating the scale.