# Increase the size of one country on a HighCharts map?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using the map of Europe from the Highcharts collection to draw choropleths.
It's geat but  have an issue with Malta being so small, it is hard for people to see it. So my question is: is there a way to increase the size of just one country on the map? I know that normally, on a map this is done with an inset, but here I would be fine with just increasing the size so it is slightly more visible.
As an example, when I look at this map, for example, Malta (just beneath Sicily at the southern tip of Italy) is very small: https://jsfiddle.net/7j9fq8h3/

```
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['dk', 0],
    ['fo', 1],
    ['hr', 2],
    ['nl', 3],
    ['ee', 4],
    ['bg', 5],
    ['es', 6],
    ['it', 7],
    ['sm', 8],
    ['va', 9],
    ['tr', 10],
    ['mt', 11],
    ['fr', 12],
    ['no', 13],
    ['de', 14],
    ['ie', 15],
    ['ua', 16],
    ['fi', 17],
    ['se', 18],
    ['ru', 19],
    ['gb', 20],
    ['cy', 21],
    ['pt', 22],
    ['gr', 23],
    ['lt', 24],
    ['si', 25],
    ['ba', 26],
    ['mc', 27],
    ['al', 28],
    ['cnm', 29],
    ['nc', 30],
    ['rs', 31],
    ['ro', 32],
    ['me', 33],
    ['li', 34],
    ['at', 35],
    ['sk', 36],
    ['hu', 37],
    ['ad', 38],
    ['lu', 39],
    ['ch', 40],
    ['be', 41],
    ['kv', 42],
    ['pl', 43],
    ['mk', 44],
    ['lv', 45],
    ['by', 46],
    ['is', 47],
    ['md', 48],
    ['cz', 49]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'custom/europe'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/custom/europe.js">Europe</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [{
        data: data,
        name: 'Random data',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false,
            format: '{point.name}'
        }
    }]
});
```

Is there any way to do this with HighMaps through the API or would my best approach be to create my own GEOJSON file for example?
Many thanks for any answers,
David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find the required path element and use translate and scale transformation on it. For example:

```
const malta = chart.series[0].points.find(p => p.name === 'Malta');
const bbox = malta.graphic.getBBox();
const centerX = bbox.width / 2 + bbox.x;
const centerY = bbox.height / 2 + bbox.y;
const scale = 3;

malta.graphic.attr({
    transform: 'translate(' +
        ((1 - scale) * centerX) + ', ' + ((1 - scale) * centerY) +
        ') scale(' + scale + ')'
}).toFront();
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ez6kr8a7/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGElement#attr

**Useful thread:** [Scale path from center](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671100/scale-path-from-center)

Comment: Thank you so much, ppotaczek, that's incredibly helpful and exactly what I need!